# Unable to have Computer Select Suit of Card in Hand

Tags: python, loops, playing-cards

I'm trying to program the card game Euchre into python and I've hit a roadblock in my code. At the beginning of each round, players take turns on deciding if they want the current face up card to represent trump for the round (if hearts is face up then hearts would be the trump in question).

I give the player the first option to decide on if they want the current trump to be called and if they pass, then let each of the other three players (all controlled by computer) to decide if they want to call the trump. Currently, I want to make it where if the computer has at least one card that matches the trump suit in their hand then they will call up the trump, otherwise I have them pass as well.

My problem is this: even if a computer has a card with the trump suit in their hand they will still pass on the trump as if they had no cards of the trump suit. So for some reason my code is not correctly checking the suits of each card in the computer's hands. Can any of you figure out what is going wrong here:

```
if 'h' in Trump_card[0]:
    trump='h'
    print("Hearts is trump.")
if 'd' in Trump_card[0]:
    trump='d'
    print("Diamonds is trump.")
if 's' in Trump_card[0]:
    trump='s'
    print("Spades is trump.")
if 'c' in Trump_card[0]:
    trump='c'
    print("Clubs is trump.")

Called_trump=raw_input("Will you call trump? (y/n): ").lower()
if Called_trump=='y':
    print("\nPlayer calls trump.")
if Called_trump=='n':
    if trump==Opp1_hand[0]:
        print("First opponent calls trump.")
    elif trump==Opp1_hand[1]:
        print("First opponent calls trump.")
    elif trump==Opp1_hand[2]:
        print("First opponent calls trump.")
    elif trump==Opp1_hand[3]:
        print("First opponent calls trump.")
    elif trump==Opp1_hand[4]:
        print("First opponent calls trump.")
    else:
        print("First opponent passes.")
        if trump in Partner_hand:
            print("Partner calls trump.")
        else:
            print("Partner passes.")
            if trump in Opp2_hand:
                print("Second opponent calls trump.")
            else:
                print("Second opponent passes.")
```

What I was trying with the Opp1_hand was explicitly taking each card in the hand and checking to see if the trump suit was found and if it was, then they'd call the trump. Then if Opp1 passed, it would give my partner a chance to see if they had the trump suit anywhere. Then if the partner passed, the second opponent would be given a chance to call trump. Thanks for any help anyone can offer.

The way I have structured Opp1_hand and Trump_card is a list of strings containing the suit and card value (for example, the Ace of spades is written as As). I'll list my code for creating all of my cards and how I created Opp1_hand and Trump_card as well below:

```
class Card(object):
    '''defines card class'''
    RANK=['9','10','J','Q','K','A']      #list of ranks & suits to make cards
    SUIT=['c','s','d','h']

    def __init__(self,rank,suit):
        self.rank=rank
        self.suit=suit

    def __str__(self):
        rep=self.rank+self.suit
        return rep

class Hand(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards=[]

    def __str__(self):
        if self.cards:
            rep=''
            for card in self.cards:
                rep+=str(card)+'\t'
        else:
            rep="EMPTY"
        return rep

    def clear(self):
        self.cards=[]

    def add(self,card):
        self.cards.append(card)

    def give(self,card,other_hand):
        self.cards.remove(card)
        other_hand.add(card)

    def remove(self,card):
        self.cards.remove(card)

class Deck(Hand):
    def populate(self):
        for suit in Card.SUIT:
            for rank in Card.RANK:
                self.add(Card(rank,suit))

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self,hands,hand_size=1):
        for rounds in range(hand_size):
            for hand in hands:
                if self.cards:
                    top_card=self.cards[0]
                    self.give(top_card,hand)
                else:
                    print("Out of cards.")
deck1=Deck()
player_hand=Hand()
partner_hand=Hand()
opp1_hand=Hand()
opp2_hand=Hand()
trump_card=Hand()
hands=[player_hand,opp1_hand,partner_hand,opp2_hand]

deck1.populate()
deck1.shuffle()
deck1.deal(hands,hand_size=5)
deck1.give(deck1.cards[0],trump_card) #this becomes the trump card players bid on

print("\nPrinting the current trump card: ")
print(trump_card)

#Converts all hands into lists that can have its elements removed
#I'm only including Opp1_hand and Trump_card here but the other three
#are made the same way
Opp1_hand=[str(opp1_hand.cards[0]),str(opp1_hand.cards[1]),str(opp1_hand.cards[2]),\
str(opp1_hand.cards[3]),str(opp1_hand.cards[4])]

Trump_card=[str(trump_card.cards[0])]
```

So an example of how Opp1_hand and Trump_hand would be displayed is:

```
Opp1_hand=['As','10d','9c','Kh','Jh']
Trump_card=['Qc']
```

What confuses me is when I was labeling what "trump" was (in the very first block of code at the top) the program was able to correctly pick out which suit ('h','s','c','d') was in Trump_card and then define trump accordingly. But when I try and check through Opp1_hand, Partner_hand, and Opp2_hand, for some reason the code won't recognize what suit each card has. If this isn't the best way to go about this, do one of you know of a better way to determine what the suit of each card is?

Comment: What is the type and contents of `Opp1_hand`? A list of strings? what do the strings look like?

Comment: What is the value in Trump_Card. I am guessing that it is a string, but would need to see where it is defined and how. From the way you use Opp1_hand I would guess that it is an array of strings. But it would be better to be sure.

Comment: Do you set Opp1_hand to a list of the suits only or is it a list of the value of the card as well as the suit? If, for example, your entry is 'Ad' for ace of diamonds, then the ifs will always fail because you are checking for 'd' and not 'Ad'

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes that the contents of the hands are single characters of the suit alone. Looking at the way you determine trump and reading the rules of Euchre implies that the hands are probably shown as suit and value (such as Ace of Diamonds). If that is the case, then Opp_hand[0] could be 'ad' and not 'd' which will fail the == test. The check for trump being in a hand would also fail because

```
x = ['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4', 'e5']
>>> 'b' in x
False
>>> 'b2' in x
True
```

You would need to show how the hands are built as well. In your test also make sure that the hands are build with the lower case letters.